# c++ Деструкторы

Tags: c++

Если я допустим выделил память в конструкторе класса для массива, можно ли без деструктора её потом освободить вне конструктора ?

```
class Myclass
{    
public:
    int* data;
    Myclass(int size)
    {    
        data = new int[size];
        cout << data << "конструктор вызвался";
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            data[i]=i;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Можно. Но не нужно - без явных к тому показаний... Просто сами потом можете запутаться, что за что отвечает...

Comment: Можете показать как ? А то на мои попытки компилятор ругается и я уже начал думать что без деструктора никак.

Comment: Компилятор чтобы помолчал, напишите пустой деструктор в класс. Но вас предупредили, что каждое использование вашего класса ведёт к утечке памяте, если вы вдруг забыли удалить данные. (*Это очень просто.*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Конструктор в данном случае ни к чему не обязывает. Член `data` всего лишь указатель.

```
class Myclass {
public:
    int* data;
    Myclass(int size) {
        data = new int[size];
        cout << data << "конструктор вызвался";
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Myclass obj;
    delete[] obj.data;
    obj.data = nullptr;
}
```